# python subprocess how to pipe stderr and stdout to stdin of second process stdin

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using subprocess to run commands that involve piping stderr and stdout to another program, something of the form `command1 2>&1 | command 2`.
Below is a toy example.

Toy `command 1`:

```
sleep 2
echo "this is not an error!"
sleep 2
(>&2 echo "THIS IS AN ERROR")
```

using `shell=True`:

```
run_string = 'bash dummy.sh 2>&1 | tee dummy.log'
ps = subprocess.Popen(run_string, shell=True)
```

I want to remove the `shell=True` and therefore cannot use `|`.

Where I'm at:

```
ps = subprocess.Popen(['bash', 'dummy.sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output = subprocess.check_output(('tee', 'dummy.log'), stdin=ps.stderr) 
#I want stdin to be both stdout and stderr.
```

I would like to pipe both stdout+stderr to the second program with subprocess, `shell=False`. 
How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`.

Comment: Duh.  Thank you. If you want some free points, you can make an answer and I'll accept it.